# make header all middle

Tags: html, css

I want to put all the header (text and pic) on the same line and in the middle of the header, but only the pic stay in the middle and no matter what I do the text still stay at the bottom of the header, someone maybe know how to solve it?

```css
body {
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    /* להשיג רישיון לפונט SPECTRUM FM */
}

.header {
    background-color: rgb(209, 45, 33);
}

.icon {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.icon:hover {
    width: 170px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.headTxt {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: rgb(234, 234, 234);
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.headTxt:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.headTxt:hover {
    color: black;
    font-size: 40px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.divHeader {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" align="center">
    <a href="index.html">
        <img src="pics/icon.png" class="icon divHeader">
    </a>
    <div class="divHeader">
        <a href="index.html" class="headTxt">
            בית
        </a>
        <a href="" class="headTxt">
            היציע המזרחי
        </a>
        <a href="" class="headTxt">
            חברות
        </a>
        <a href="" class="headTxt">
            תמונות
        </a>
        <a href="" class="headTxt">
            צור קשר
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want your menu items to overlay the image in the center? I'd also suggest using `transform: scale()` instead of changing the font size on `:hover` so your page doesn't bounce around from the text size change if that's the effect you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Change as below.

HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <a href="index.html">
        <img src="pics/icon.png" class="icon divHeader">
    </a>
    <div class="divHeader">
        <a href="index.html" class="headTxt">
            בית
        </a>
        <a href="" class="headTxt">
            היציע המזרחי
        </a>
        <a href="" class="headTxt">
            חברות
        </a>
        <a href="" class="headTxt">
            תמונות
        </a>
        <a href="" class="headTxt">
            צור קשר
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI',             
Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans- 
serif;
    /* להשיג רישיון לפונט SPECTRUM FM */
    }

.header {
    background-color: rgb(209, 45, 33);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.icon {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.icon:hover {
    width: 170px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.headTxt {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: rgb(234, 234, 234);
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.headTxt:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.headTxt:hover {
    color: black;
    font-size: 40px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.divHeader {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI',             
Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans- 
serif;
    /* להשיג רישיון לפונט SPECTRUM FM */
    }

.header {
    background-color: rgb(209, 45, 33);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction:column;
}

.icon {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.icon:hover {
    width: 170px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.headTxt {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: rgb(234, 234, 234);
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.headTxt:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.headTxt:hover {
    color: black;
    font-size: 40px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.divHeader {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <a href="index.html">
        <img src="pics/icon.png" class="icon divHeader">
    </a>
    <div class="divHeader">
        <a href="index.html" class="headTxt">
            בית
        </a>
        <a href="" class="headTxt">
            היציע המזרחי
        </a>
        <a href="" class="headTxt">
            חברות
        </a>
        <a href="" class="headTxt">
            תמונות
        </a>
        <a href="" class="headTxt">
            צור קשר
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Only you have to add " flex-direction : column " CSS to header.